# What does this myCar evaluate to? Is it the return value of somePart()?

Tags: java

What does this myCar evaluate to? Is it the return value of somePart()?

```
boolean myCar = true || somePart();
```

Comment: `somePart` will only be evaluated if the first condition is false, hence it will never be evaluated. The && and || operators perform Conditional-AND and Conditional-OR operations on two boolean expressions. These operators exhibit "short-circuiting" behavior, which means that the second operand is evaluated only if needed. http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

Comment: I am not trying to sound rude, but the best way to learn would be to try and write a sample program that you could use to test it and see what the result is.

Comment: In Java, there is `boolean` and not `bool`. So Edited.

Comment: This can be a serious problem if your application depends on you running `somePart()`. As it stands, it never will.

Answer (score 2):

The `||` operator is called a "short-circuit" operator, because if it finds that evaluating the left operand results in `true`, it will not bother evaluating the right operand. In your case, `true` is `true`, so `somePart()` will not be called.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume it would always return true. Infact somePart() would never be evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

it's evaluated to true, somePart() is never called.

Answer (score 1):

It will always return `true`, as a result of [Short-circuit Evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Answer (score 1):

Read it out loud.

```
"myCar equals TRUE -or- somePart()"
```

We can short circuit the function evaluation since the first condition always returns true.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a `|| operator` between true and `somePart()`, it would always return true.

It checks if either of the condition is true, if it finds such a condition which is true, then it is set to true. This is the an indirect reason why the call to `somePart()` is never evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

This will always return true even if somePart() returns false. Because somePart() will not even be executed. JVM optimizes logical expressions and does not run the rest of expression if the result is known anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It will be true. Always. Because of the behavior of the logical or operator is this:

```
Input 1  Input 2   Output
-------  -------   ------
0        0         0
0        1         1
1        0         1
1        1         1
```

Comment: One of the columns in the truth table should only be `true`